# ASP.NET DateTime.Now appeared frozen on a single page

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I had a pretty strange problem this morning with one of my websites.  The date reporting for some user selected days was off by one day.  The website allows users to select from three days ('Today', 'Tomorrow', and 'Day After Tomorrow') then translates the selected day into an actual date (today would look like '12/14').

The page was working fine last night, but it somehow appears when midnight rolled over the day did not update to the current day.

The page uses .Net `DateTime.Now` to get the current date then offsets the day by +0, +1, or +2 depending on the users selected day.

I checked the system time on the site and it was correct.  DateTime.Now was also working just fine on other pages in the website.

I ended up just republishing the entire site (minus web.config) to the server and it fixed the problem.  But my question is, how did this happen in the first place?  I am just kind of curious what could cause DateTime.Now to not update on a single page and would like to prevent it from happening again.

The site is hosted using IIS on a Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual machine.

Let me know if more information is needed and I will do my best to update the question.

Comment: Does that specific page have caching enabled?

Comment: Yes.  But can one user sitting on a page cause caching of a datetime for a different user?  Also, really, -1?  I did research on this and found nothing, it is pretty clear what the problem is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client side caching (browser didn't think it needed a new file), server side caching (server didn't think you needed a new file, you'd probably know about this one), or the server is in a different time zone than you (the date change time is x hours later than your local midnight).

You have to tell asp.net to discourage caching to get a page to regenerate, but that will make for worse performance, sometimes dramatically worse. Consider using javascript or donut hole caching.

Comment: I like you also mentioned possible time zone issue. +1

Comment: Thanks!  I will look into using donut hole caching, and in the mean time advise users not idle on this particular page.

Comment: Well, I hate to admit this, but I found the problem.  After a ton of troublshooting, trying donut caching and disabling the entire sites client side caching the datetime was still not properly updating if the user left the page open when the date changed.  Turns out I had the class variable declaired as a static...removing it fixed the problem.  Thanks again for the help, this whole ordeal taught me a new concept (donut and donut hole caching)!